# Internet Explorer 10 hiding buttons or preventing JavaScript from working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-10

I'm not normally in a need to ask basic or vague JavaScript questions on SO, so pardon me if there is little details here - I'm not sure how to get more.

In the online user manual I'm maintaining, I'm adding custom buttons on each page to get a direct link to the current page (otherwise grabbing the URL just brings you to the home screen), as well as a few extra features. These buttons are added using Javascript, or rather they are already hidden in the HTML, are updated after an AJAX call and then displayed.

It has taken me a *lot* of work to get these working, in Firefox, Chrome, IE6, 7, 8, 9, I'm sure you know how these things go.

Now comes IE10 with yet another really weird behavior that I want to bang my head on the wall for. If you visit http://help.objectiflune.com/en/knowledgebase/ you will see those buttons on the right inside the main frame. They're grey and blue, top of the page.

So this first "welcome" page is fine, it works great, no issue. However, if you navigate to any sub page using the TOC on the left (such as Error Codes -> PlanetPress Design -> PlanetPress Design Error PXXXX), the buttons all disappear.

I've also noticed that if you get the URL for the page itself (inside the frame, again) and you open it in another tab, it first does not show them, but then refreshing the page makes the buttons appear.

I've tried using the F12 developper console, but it requires refreshing the page to show the console so I can`t use it in those new tabs. As for using within the whole frame system, it doesn't seem to be showing me any errors, nothing weird.

Again I'm sorry if this is an "it's not working" with no further technical details, but... there are none I know how to give.

**UPDATE**: For the specific code, please turn to http://help.objectiflune.com/common/scripts/olCommon.js , and look at the function starting at line 207 (`function buildMenu()`). this is the function that retrieves the information and displays the appropriate menus, such as `$("#guidebuttons").show();`

Comment: You're using Flash there, aren't you? IE10 Metro requires special handling of Flash.

Comment: Barmar, there is Flash on this, yes, as there is a small flash tool that makes it possible to copy the URL to the clipboard. However, the display of all those buttons is (or should be) independant of Flash. The buttons are HTML+CSS, the display is done using jQuery.

Comment: I can't be sure, and the only way I can test IE10 is with BrowserStack, but I suspect that's the source of the problem. Although it doesn't explain why it's only an issue when you drill down deeply.

Comment: the drill down is the fastest way to experience the issue but if you go back to the same page it does does it too. In fact, I now see that refreshing just the frame will make it work, in one or two tries. Seems too random for me, I really have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

In ObjectifLune.css, #buttoncontainer has `display: none`.  Navigating through the F12 window, the display of that object is `none`:

[image]

I would guess that somewhere in your JS, you're setting the display to `block`, but there's something wrong with that code in IE.

Comment: "Something wrong with that code in IE10"... perhaps, but without more precision on how IE10 handles a simple JS code that shows something hidden, randomly, where all other versions handle it perfectly, I'm no closer to an answer.

Comment: The code is a little extensive with all the JavaScript, jQuery and AJAX calls involved in the whole transation. However I'll put more details to find that code in the question.

Comment: I took a quick look at `olCommon.js`.  It seems to me that the buttons are created in line 303 and added to the body in line 305.  I don't see where in that file the buttons actually get displayed (remember that #buttoncontainer is set to `display:none`).  I would suggest inserting `$("#buttoncontainer").show();` as line 306.

Comment: Thank ic3b3rg, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to change anything. Not only does this not explain it working some of the time, it doesn't explain why hidden buttons would show up on all browsers except the latest one! I think it's a much deeper issue than this.